# Replace an URL with an new URL which has a "?" in it

Tags: customization, urls

I cannot find any way to replace automatically an url with a new url which has a “?” in its URL :-( It get just cut off everything after the first “?” including the “?” too eachtime I tried it.

How to handle this issue?

Comment: Replace the URL in what context?

Comment: What do you mean? I mean EACH urls from my blogpostings and pages.

Comment: You mean in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending any parameters to the url you should use add_query_args https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Comment: Thank your! I really understand nothing of this but I redirect it to my coder. Hopefully he can make it with your help.

Comment: Unfortunately it also did not work corretcly when he tried it via sql command. Any further ideas how to handle it?

Comment: It would be best if you could provide some sort of context to your question with what you are trying to achieve. Please explain with some examples of your URLs